# Paypal REST API - Billing agreement

Tags: paypal, billing

Using Paypal Classic API Billing agreement can be created. Agreement Id can be used for future payment using Paypal reference transaction.

Can this same functionality achieved using Paypal REST API? If yes please help me providing reference. I'm aware Billing Plan and Billing agreement can be created using Paypal REST API but without Billing Plan billing agreement can't be created.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Billing agreement" in RESTful APIs is specificly for Recurring Payments, and that might have misled you.

The terms are slightly different between Classic APIs and the RESTful APIs, and Reference Transactions is pretty equivalent to what is called "future payments" in RESTful APIs.

Technical specs are listed [HERE](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/blob/master/docs/future_payments_mobile.md), pls be noted that as of now, future payment has to work with mobile integration on top of PayPal MSDK (to obtain user consent and auth code)

Comment: Thanks for your response. So, If I need to give option of 'Billing agreement' to the customer on my web application for future payment. Then I've to use classic API. Is this correct?

Comment: That's correct, as of now you've to continue using classis APIs for web integration of "future payments"

Answer (score 0):

Now this feature is available in REST APIs also. But please note this is a vetted product from PayPal. Not every merchant will be approved to use the Pre-Approved payments . Docs are available - But as a limited release

[Docs for PayPal Reference transaction API. Also called as pre-approved payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/limited-release/reference-transactions/api/)